# How to know if a new rule/ removing a rule in natural deduction is still sound/complete?

Tags: natural-deduction

I'm generally confused about how to work this out, these are the questions that have been given to me, and I just don't know where to start on them:

1. Consider the set of natural deduction rules, is the set of natural deduction without the rule RAA sound, and complete?

How do I go about figuring this out? check if the set of rules are still sound and complete?

2. State whether this new rule:

--
⊥

is sound, and complete? 
How would I also go about figuring this out? I'm guessing it wouldn't be sound because true doesn't evaluate to false.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your attempts!

Comment: "Consider the set of natural deduction rules, " ...  *Which* set of natural deduction rules?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more directly addressed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic .  Some laws of logic are weakened or dismissed yet allow for non-trivial conclusions.

Foundational bases for classical logic can be uprooted, like the idea that statements must either be true or false: [Deviant Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviant_logic)

Variations on the [Law of Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) have implications in programming.

In addition to varying the foundational rules of logic themselves, you can vary commonly accepted axiomsrr. [Non-Euclidean Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry) was discovered when Gauss and others rejected the parallel principle and were able to develop consistent theorems.